# Is there anyway to check what the calling class is?

Tags: apex

Is there a way to grab say SomeTrigger.class or SomeTest.test as the calling class within apex?

From what I can understand the request is that our helper class would tailor its response based on which class called it based on the limitations of the expected endpoint. EG(If the expected endpoint was chatter it would avoid using certain tags) my response internally has been I don't think this is possible in any good way.

What has been used is below:

```java
    public with sharing class CallerSensitive {
    
        private static System.Type callingType;
    
        public static System.Type set(System.Type callType){
            if(callingType == null){
                callingType = callType;
            }
            return callingType;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: What does "triggering class" mean?

Comment: Do you mean something like "which class was the first to start running in this transaction?". If so, I believe the answer is no. Also, why do you want this information? It seems like you're trying to use this to solve a larger problem. What is the overall goal here?

Comment: Note that it is advised that you have only one Trigger handler per object. However, even if you follow that you may still have one more than (from various packages). At this time, you cannot know which trigger is running.

Comment: From what I can understand the request is that our helper class would tailor its response based on which class called it based on the limitations of the expected endpoint. EG(If the expected endpoint was chatter it would avoid using certain tags) my response internally has been I don't think this is possible in any good way.

Comment: Rather than just add this information as a comment, please edit your original question to include those details. I haven't downvoted, but I suspect had that been included from the start that you wouldn't have been downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most correct term to use here is the "calling class", and No, there is not an out-of-the-box way to determine that.

The closest thing you'd get to this is to have the class where you want this information require its callers to provide their type in the constructor (and remove any no-arg constructor that you have). Something like

```java
public class CallerSensitive{
    System.Type callingType;

    public CallerSensitive(System.Type caller){
        callingType = caller;
    }
}
```

which would then be called like so

```java
public class Client{
    public void doWork(){
        CallerSensitive provider = new CallerSensitive(Client.class);
    }
}
```

The [Quiddity enum](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm) can tell you a little bit about the overall transaction, but it's limited to telling you if you're running from Visualforce, batch apex, synchronous apex, etc...

Honestly though, I think the best approach here would be something like [the strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). That is, have each separate behavior be its own class (or perhaps its own inner class), have them conform to a common interface (via implementing an interface, or extending a virtual/abstract class), and then make it the responsibility of the client code to select the appropriate strategy.

Comment: Oh I am not disagreeing with you here this is just what I've been handed make X work.

Comment: @KarlLivesey If you're being told "make this feature work", that's fine. It's an entirely different story if you're being told "make this feature work by doing X,Y,Z". Requests we developers get should really only cover the "what" and not touch on the "how". Whoever is telling you to figure out the caller obviously has little idea about Apex and has no business dictating such things.

Comment: my solution was similar to yours the only difference was it was static and so would have a method that would check if it had been set if it had would take this and respond with the class sent in otherwise would respond with the original class yeah I've just been given this to do.